# running batch files inside another batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have made a batch script to run some .exe files and .bat files. The format of the script is as follows:

```
a.exe
b.exe
c.bat
d.bat
e.bat
f.exe
g.exe
```

but the problem is when I run the script it is only executed till c.bat. d.bat is not executing. Is there any problem in writing the batch script for executing other batch files?

Comment: Batch files must be executed via CALL command: `call c.bat`   `call d.bat` ...

Comment: will they be executed one after another? I mean after finishing of one, another will start @Aacini

Comment: Yes.  They will all execute single threaded.  One after the other. They will not run in parallel.

Comment: but the execution stops after d.bat @Squashman

Comment: Is `c.bat` left running, running into an error, being exited in a more forceful way? Is `d.bat` having any of these issues?

Comment: Unfortunately none of us are omniscient.  We would need more details on what the EXE files do and what is the code inside each batch file.  Why did you update your question with more files?

Answer (score 3):

just in case you missed the full application of `call`

```
a.exe
b.exe
call c.bat
call d.bat
call e.bat
f.exe
g.exe
```

is how your script should now look.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the 'call' command, the batch files next batch/exe file wouldn't execute unless the batch file stops. Instead, use the 'start' command. that way, it'll execute the batch in a new window